# Is it correct that these specific pointers are adjacent in memory?

Tags: c

given the following code:

```
int** GradeStat(int* Grades, int size_grades, int grd_range, int* count_grd, int* avg_grd) {
    const int len = 100/grd_range+1;
    int** collector = malloc(len * sizeof(int*));
    size_t i;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
         collector[i] = malloc(count_grd[i] * sizeof(int));
    }
    return collector;
}
```

Is it correct to assume that for any `0<j<len` the following is correct: `collector[j]=collector[j-1]+1`?

Comment: No that is not guaranteed.

Comment: It's actually unlikely. Many `malloc()` implementations put bookkeeping information in the memory before the beginning of the allocation. So you would not expect any two allocations to be contiguous.

Comment: Also, `malloc` can set aside more memory than was requested, to make its memory management easier.

Comment: Test it out yourself.

Comment: First the C language standard doesn't say anything must be true about different `malloc` returns. Even in practice, if the `count_grd[i]` values are greater than 1, adjacent `collector[i]` values can _never_ be one apart. The location `collector[i] + 1` lies within the block pointed to by `collector[i]`.

Comment: Contiguous allocation is a recommended programming technique for making progress on your question. —R

Comment: I *believe* its even undefined behaviour to compare those two pointers.

Comment: @kopecs: Comparing unrelated pointers for equality is defined. Comparing for order (`<` etc.) is not.